# In ArcMap, is there a tool/script that allows you to attribute a line based on an attribute of a point and hatching?

Tags: arcmap, point, line, fields-attributes

I have a large amount of lines that run through a number of points that have different values. The lines have hatching which represent what direction the line is running. Currently, I am having to attribute each individual line to have the value of the desired point. Is there a tool/ a Python Script I could write that would automate this process?[image]

Here is an image of what my project roughly looks like. I would want the middle line to have the value of 20 and the far left line to have the value of 10. I can't find a tool that does exactly what I want. Any suggestionss?

Answer (score 0):

Spatial join will work like a charm in this situation. Firstly create start point of lines by [feature vertices to point](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) tool. It will generate a new point feature class then run [Spatial join](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) between newly created feature class and your points (layer which holds the desired data). This will also generate a new point feature class. Finally attribute join between this feature class and your lines on the basis of unique field (objectID).

Comment: I don't believe spatial join will be useful as there is not a match option which will attribute all the vertices turned points correctly.